# Помогите написать бота в VK на питоне через VK api / longpoll

Tags: python

Только начал программировать на питоне, много раз переделывал код и даже использовал другие библиотеки, но что-то ничего не помогает, походу я просто криворукий.

Покажите, пожалуйста, бота, который на новое сообщение будет отвечать `ПРИВЕТ`.

Напишите и проверьте его сами, пожалуйста, потому что большинство того, что есть в интернете, не работает...

Comment: то есть вы просите написать за вас вашу программу, протестить её за вас и дать вам исходники? Зачем кому то это делать?

Comment: Разве плохо, что новичок просит помощи в этом деле? Да и программа займет максимум 10 строк, она простейшая...

Answer (score 1):

Подставьте свои данные вместо `[access_token]` и `[group_id]`:

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


vk_session = VkApi(token='[access_token]')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '[group_id]')  # v5.103
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            vk.messages.send(
                random_id=get_random_id(),
                peer_id=event.obj['message']['peer_id'],
                message='ПРИВЕТ',
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```